# Suppress "unused" still gives warning in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javabeans

We have code like this:

```
class GetXyzResponseBean {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final List<Foo> foos;
    public GetXyzResponseBean(List<Foo> foos) { this.foos = ...
}
```

Basically a simple bean class that we use in conjunction with GSON. So some part of our code creates an instance of this class (passing in that list), and then JAX RS / gson magic turns that into JSON for consumption by some REST client.

Thing is: although the above uses @SuppressWarnings ... I still get a warning in Intellij, suggesting that I should fix it by turning it into a local variable.

Which is *not* what I want. I want to keep the code like it is, and to not be bothered with a warning here! I also don't want to add a *getter* method for this field. Because the intention is that this is a "write only" container.

Comment: `final` for write only?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `final` is like the "preferred default" for me. We always go for immutable where possible. But I agree, this doesn't really add value here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the suppress warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings ("FieldCanBeLocal")
```

and since, in your case it's unused you may wanna use the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings ({"FieldCanBeLocal", "unused"})
```

Here's a (non exhaustive?) list of suppress warnings: https://gist.github.com/elevenetc/bf795f94aaf3e92169ef

Answer (score 1):

[Suppress the warning inside of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html) instead of suppressing it at any other level.

Navigate to Editor > Inspections > Java > Class structure, and untick "Field can be local".

[image]

Comment: Makes sense as well, but I prefer the other answer a bit as that works for other IntelliJ users as well.